# How to reorganize a dataframe in order to increase dimensionality?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science

I have an existing data frame with 3 columns: `location` ,`contaminants` and `Concentration`.

It looks something like this:

| Location | Contaminants | Concentration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | Chlorine | 10 |
| Los Angeles | Lead | 5 |
| Los Angeles | Chlorine | 2 |
| Miami | Sulfur | 5 |
| Miami | Lead | 4 |

I need to sort it so that there is only one row per `location` which contains the concentration for each contaminant in order to make it ideal for machine learning.

I need it to look like this:

| Location | Chlorine Concentration | Lead Concentration | Sulfur Concentration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYC | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| Los Angeles | 2 | 5 | 0 |
| Miami | 0 | 4 | 5 |

I'm trying to do this in pandas-- thank you so much for the help!

Right now, its not in a compatible form. There needs to be only one row per location, but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pandas.pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to transform your data from long to wide format

example code using sample data:

```
df.pivot(index='Location', columns='Contaminants', values='Concentration').fillna(0)
```

which outputs:

```
| Contaminants | Chlorine | Lead | Sulfur |
|     Location |          |      |        |
|--------------|----------|------|--------|
|  Los Angeles |      2.0 |  5.0 |    0.0 |
|        Miami |      0.0 |  4.0 |    5.0 |
|          NYC |     10.0 |  0.0 |    0.0 |
```

be aware of `fillna`, which is used to replace non-exist value to zero